# MariaDB starts without errors and doesn't run

Tags: database, shell, ubuntu-14.04, mariadb

I start my mariadb with

> /etc/init.d/mysql start

Then i get

> - starting MariaDB database server mysqld

No more messages. 
When i call

> service mysql status

i get

> MariaDB is stopped

**Why ?**

---

my **my.cnf** is:

```
# Example mysql config file.

[client-server]
socket=/tmp/mysql-dbug.sock
port=3307

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
[client]
password=XXXXXX

# Here are entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
temp-pool
key_buffer_size=16M
datadir=/etc/mysql/data
loose-innodb_file_per_table

[mariadb]  
datadir=/etc/mysql/data
default-storage-engine=aria
loose-mutex-deadlock-detector
max- connections=20

[mariadb-5.5]
language=/my/maria-5.5/sql/share/english/
socket=/tmp/mysql-dbug.sock
port=3307

[mariadb-10.1]
language=/my/maria-10.1/sql/share/english/
socket=/tmp/mysql2-dbug.sock

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet=16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
loose-abort-source-on-error
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: And what does your log say? Generally that is in `/var/log/mysql/error.log` in Ubuntu. `tail -50 /var/log/mysql/error.log` will probably capture enough to tell you what's going on.

Comment: and `mysqld.err`

Comment: and syslog / journal

Comment: mysql.err is empty - mysqld.err was not found - in /var/log/mysql are some files named 'mariadb-bin.001234' and a mariadb-bin.index. There are no logs anywhere wich helps to resolve the error.

Comment: That's because the error log gets redirected to syslog / journal. Right after you got "MariaDB is stopped", try to run something like `sudo journalctl -lxn 100` . If it shows nothing, try `sudo less /var/log/syslog`.

Comment: thanks @elenst there was the file mysqld_safe missing. New one created and the result is now: `0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in #007/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/lib/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!`

Comment: there runs a mongo DB parallel ... can this be the problem maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

If your SELinux is set to permissive, please try to adjust the permissions :
Files in /var/lib/mysql should be 660.
/var/lib/mysql directory should be 755, Any of its subdirectories should be 700.

if your SELinux is set to enforcing, Please apply the right context.